# how to control what opening the laptops lid does

Tags: power-management, lid

my laptop's lid is a little broken and when i put it in it's bag it'll be open while i'm handling it and then it get's out of the suspend mode, how can i change what opening the lid does, i only found how to change what closing the lid does in Power Manager, but there was no option to control what opening the lid does :D

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, but I think this can qualify as an answer.
I'm almost 100% sure that the BIOS controls this function, and not the operating system. You can look in your BIOS settings, but it's doubtful there will be something to disable this.

Comment: thanks @Zacharee1, i'll look at the BIOS but i know that OS can control that too, in win7 when i set the "what closing the lid does" to "do nothing" it also doesn't do anything when i open the lid, and the laptop will still be in sleep mode, tnx

Comment: Closing the lid isn't the same as opening it. Windows can control what happens when you close the lid, since Windows is running. When the computer is asleep, though, Windows isn't doing anything and can't control what the computer does. That's why the BIOS needs to control this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try edit */etc/systemd/logind.conf*. Set the option to ignore the lid switch instead of suspend.

> HandleLidSwitch=ignore

loose the `#` sign. Then restart.

Comment: thanks@VRR, but i can't do this, "permission denied", i'm the only user of the computer, i don't konw why?

Comment: Try `sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf`. You need root access to edit it.

Comment: i did it :D , i finally could change it to "ignore" but laptop still wakes up when i open the lid :(

Comment: Did you restart after saving changes?

Comment: yes i did, but nothing changed

Comment: You deleted the `#` sign in front of `HandleLidSwitch`, too.Strange, it did well for me. Perhaps this [post](http://superuser.com/questions/67814/preventing-laptop-wake-up-when-opening-the-lid-on-linux) might be interesting for you.